# I want to get 3 result of SQL query in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have result set which has 3 records for each set. I want them to be in one row instead of 3 rows.

I want to get specific values only from that row.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use aggregate function

```
select col1,col3,min(timestamp1) as timestamp1,
min(timestamp2) as timestamp2,min(timestamp3) as timestamp3
from t group by  col1,col3
```

Comment: Your query is giving min of (timestamp 1) in value where as I want to get value highlighted in yellow. If you check column timestamp 1 I want to extract value in yellow color not mix or max of set.

Comment: @Sahil . . . (1) You have highlighted the minimum timestamp.  (2) SQL tables (and result sets) represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering -- and no such column is obvious in your data.

Comment: If you can see timestamp1 is value coming from column 2 value is abc. 2) timestamp2 value is coming from column 2 value is xyz. 3) timestamp 3 value is coming from column 2 value is pqr.Please let me know if you not clear with requirement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : please dont get confuse with data. Its a dummy data. Requirement is to get highlighted values. Neither thats the max or min value.

Comment: @Sahil it seams you are not understanding what GordonLinoff meant with "SQL tables (and result sets) represent unordered sets. There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering -- and no such column is obvious in your data" You seam to be wanting the select the "first" record for timestamp1 column, the "second" record for the timestamp2 column and so on.. But there is no thing like "insert" order and "first" and "second" in SQL, without a column on which we can identify the order by like a auto_increment column and use `ORDER BY` on

Comment: @Sahil . . . You should clarify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select col1, col3,
       max(case when column2 = 'abc' then timestamp1 end) as timestamp1,
       max(case when column2 = 'xyz' then timestamp2 end) as timestamp2,
       max(case when column2 = 'pqr' then timestamp3 end) as timestamp3
from t
group by col1, col3;
```

Note:  I have Zaynul's answer actually makes more sense to me based on the provided data.  It is simpler to assume that the desired results are the minimum values.  However, this is also a valid interpretation of the question, and is clarified in the comments on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the exact logic you would apply but from the question to me it seems like you just need to solve the data frame alignment problem and a query like below should solve if that is what you are looking for,

```
Select 
    Column1, Column2,
    (select timestamp1 from table 
     where (your logic to filter)) as T1, 
    (select timestamp2 from table 
     where (your logic to filter)) as T2, 
    (select timestamp3 from table 
     where (your logic to filter)) as T3 
from 
    table 
where 
    (your master filter);
```